# JQuery selecting by name issue

Tags: jquery, syntax, jquery-selectors

I have this input field

```
<input name="Ops[2][Duration]" type="text" value="1" row-number="2">
```

Which I'm trying to select by name but it seems that

```
$('input[name=Ops[2][Duration]]');
```

Gets confused with all the brackets. How can I sort this out ? I tried

```
$('input[name=Ops\[2\]\[Duration\]]');
```

But that didn't work either, I still get:

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=Ops[2][Duration]]

Comment: You have missed to wrap the attribute value with double quotes,it as to be like this $('input[name="Ops[2][Duration]"]');

Answer (score 2):

In a jQuery selector the escape character is two backslashes: `\\`:

```
$('input[name=Ops\\[2\\]\\[Duration\\]]');
```

Alternatively you could put the attribute value in quotes:

```
$('input[name="Ops[2][Duration]"]');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the attribute value in quotes:

```
$('input[name="Ops[2][Duration]"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the name attribute value in paired quotes

```
$('input[name="Ops[2][Duration]"]');
```

or

```
$("input[name='Ops[2][Duration]']");
```

```js
$(function(){
    $('input[name="Ops[2][Duration]"]').on('blur', function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="Ops[2][Duration]" type="text" value="1" row-number="2">
```